# How to configure UTF-8 encoding on incoming emails in MS Outlook?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2013

I checked the MS Outlook (office 365, 2013 and 2010) for options to configure UTF-8 character encoding.

I found the options for out going email in: File > Options > Advanced > International Options.

BUT

I am not able to find the option to configure of incoming emails. Does anybody have any idea about this?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the encoding of a particular email from *Actions* (Move menu) > *Other Actions* >  *Encoding* > *More*

[image]

Comment: How to do that in Outlook 365? Or just "Outlook" from Office16? It has no "Actions" button.

Answer (score 1):

Incoming messages cannot be changed - it is up to the **sender** to chose a particular encoding. Outlook parses the incoming MIME messages into multiple MAPI properties.

What is it exactly that you are trying to solve? Why would you want to do anything with incoming messages?

Comment: I have this client how has reported that in outlook UTF-8 encoded characters are not displaying properly. But in other email clients and even gmail and other browser based email clients the characters are display properly.

Comment: I have never seen Outlook decoding UTF-8 data improperly. You might want to post the full MIME source (you can get it from Gmail) of a problematic message.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - I just stumbled on this old thread. It seems Outlook (2010) rules don't filter text that's UTF8-encoded. So filtering on subject "foo" won't find that text when it's encoded by the sender, but it's easily visible in the UI. I'm now looking for a solution, with VBA to decode and resave headers prior to processing by native filters, or to decode and do all filtering in VBA or other code. I have an old version of Redemption, I dunno if that would be useful here. Does Office 365 or 2016 do better in this area?

Comment: I am not aware of any problems in that area. Again, Rules do not look at the MIME headers, they extract PR_SUBJECT_W property (UTF16 encoded, just like all other Unicode properties in Outlook) or (if the store is an ANSI PST) at PR_SUBJECT_A (single byte encoded with the charset specified by the PR_INTERNET_CPID property. In that case I can imagine Unicode problems.